# fullcalendar - how to format the small date in a customized view?

Tags: json, fullcalendar

Is it possible to format the small date for example `Wed 8/8`(red arrow in the picture) to a longer format (green arrow in the picture) such as `Tue 14 Aug 2018`?

See the image attached.

I can't find anything in the documentation.

Here is my json for the view:

```
timelineSevenDays: {
  type: 'timeline',
  duration: { days: 7 },
  dateIncrement:{ days: 3 },
  titleFormat: 'ddd DD MMM YYYY'
}
```

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bO6p.png)

Comment: You should do try doing something yourself before asking for help.

Comment: Use `slotLabelFormat` https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat